# ¿Como calcular los valores de varios checkbox con un botón calcular en js?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Verán, tengo 15 checkbox y cada uno tiene un precio, lo que quiero es que sume los que sean seleccionados al oprimir el botón calcular, podrían ser tan amables de darme una idea? Es en js, php

Comment: Para poderte apoyar hace falta que leas por favor [ask], edites y nos compartas aquello que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="20"> 20 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="30"> 30 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="40"> 40 <br>
</div>
<button type="button" id='sumar'>sumar</button> <br>
Total = <span id='total'>0</span>

<script>
    $('#sumar').click(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        $('.checkbox').each(function (index, element) {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                total += parseInt($(this).val())
            }
        });
        $('#total').text(total)
    })
</script>
```